# How to make bot send multiple reply for 1 commmand

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to make a bot send multiple commands reply with one command. example like tags.

```
browsers = ['chrome', 'mozilla', 'ie', 'safari']

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def chrome(ctx):
    msg = "about Chrome. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mozilla(ctx):
    msg = "about Mozilla. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def safari(ctx):
    msg = "about Safari. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

So finally if a user types `?browsers` command it should send all commands reply in `browsers` list. also it should work seperately if typed `?chrome`  or `?mozilla` or `?safari`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way I could find to do it, but it's a little awkward.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def chrome(ctx):
    msg = "about Chrome. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def mozilla(ctx):
    msg = "about Mozilla. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def safari(ctx):
    msg = "about Safari. {0.author.mention}".format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)

@bot.group(pass_context=True)
async def browsers(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        for command in browsers.walk_commands():
            await command.invoke(ctx)

browsers.add_command(chrome)
browsers.add_command(mozilla)
browsers.add_command(safari)
```

I very much suspect that there's a cleaner way to do this, where you define the commands with `@browsers.command()`, and then also make them available to invoke directly, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: i getting error while running bot. `in <module>
    browsers.add(chrome)
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: @Demotry It's actually `add_command`, I just forgot the right name.

Comment: Yes its working perfect. but `browsers.add_command(firefox)`  this should be `browsers.add_command(mozilla)`  Thank you.